# Ansible run role based on condition

Tags: ansible, roles

I'm using Ansible to install an agent on Linux servers.  There are different install procedures based on if the system is running systemd or initd.  I created a role for both install procedures, but I want to see if the server is running systemd or initd first and then run the corresponding role.  Below is the code I have created.  Will this type of conditional work this way or am I missing the mark?

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: check if running initd or systemd and role the correct role
      command: pidof systemd
      register: pid_systemd

    - name: check if running initd or systemd and role the correct role
      command: pidof /sbin/init
      register: pid_initd

    - include_role:
        name: install-appd-machine-agent-initd
      when: pid_initd.stdout == '1'

    - include_role:
        name: install-appd-machine-agent-systemd
      when: pid_systemd.stdout == '1'
```

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: I have a newer test node that runs systemd and it works but unfortunately I don’t have an older node running initd to see if the condition truly works.

Comment: I did run the specific commands on servers running in production and they both return a value of 1.

Comment: You would probably be better off looking at the return code of `pidof` rather than the output (you can get multiple pids returned by `pidof systemd` on a multi-user system due to systemd user instances). Alternately, you can examine `/sbin/init`; on systemd-enabled system that will be a symlink to systemd.

Comment: the [`"ansible_service_mgr": "systemd"`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.9.13/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/system/service_mgr.py#L139) hostvar may interest you

Comment: The automatic fact `ansible_service_mgr` as @mdaniel pointed out, should be the preferred method than running `command`s to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible collects facts of a system using `gather_facts` via [`setup`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/setup_module.html) module. This provides a magic variable called `ansible_service_mgr`. This variable can be used to conditionally execute tasks.

For example, to run your roles conditionally:

```yml
  tasks:
  - include_role:
      name: install-appd-machine-agent-initd
    when: ansible_service_mgr == "sysvinit"
  - include_role:
      name: install-appd-machine-agent-systemd
    when: ansible_service_mgr == "systemd"
```